# BuildRenderTree is not called in a razor page that inherits of my custom component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I have the following files:

**BaseComponent.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

namespace Test.Pages;

[Route("/basepage")]

public class BasePage :ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        var seq = 0;
        builder.OpenElement(seq, "h3");
        builder.AddContent(++seq, "BuildRenderTree of BasePage.cs");
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

**CustomNonRazorPage.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

namespace Xcition.Client.Pages;

[Route("/customnonrazorpage")]
public class CustomNonRazorPage : BasePage
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        var seq = 0;
        builder.OpenElement(seq, "h3");
        builder.AddContent(++seq, "BuildRenderTree of CustomNonRazorPage.cs");
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

**CustomPage.razor**:

```
@inherits BasePage
@page "/custompage"

<h3>CustomPage.razor</h3>
```

I call the following relative URI in the browser:

- `/basepage`: returns a page with `BuildRenderTree` of `BasePage.cs` OK, it calls its own `BuildRenderTree` method
- `/customnonrazorpage`: returns a page with `BuildRenderTree` of `BasePage.cs` and `BuildRenderTree` of `CustomNonRazorPage.cs` OK, it calls the `BuildRenderTree` method of `BasePage`
- `/custompage`: returns a page with `CustomPage.razor` Unexpected value because it doesn't call the `BuildRenderTree` method of `BasePage`

May be I'm doing something wrong because I'm a beginner in Blazor.

I would like to create my custom base component that surrounds with an another component the body of a child razor component that inherits of my custom base component (something like the Layouts do).

I try to explain it better with an example:

- `FinalComponent.razor` that inherits from `BaseComponent` and with a body like "My final content".
- `BaseComponent.cs` that implements in `BuildRenderTree` the code that surrounds `[Parameter] RenderFragment` body with the `OtherComponent`
- `OtherComponent.razor` that contains `<div>@Body</div>`

I would like to get the final result like this:

```
<div><h3>My final content</h3></div>
```

The target is to be able to decide by code in the `BaseComponent` what is the the class that I would use for the `OtherComponent` without need to know it from the `FinalComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, essentially in the same way as in your CustomNonRazorPage

```
@inherits BasePage
@page "/custompage"

@{ base.BuildRenderTree(__builder); }

<h3>CustomPage.razor</h3>
```

but besides being ugly that `__builder` is a hack, no warranties.

Comment: Now I understand that the code of my child component is inserted in the BuildRenderTree, and forcing the call to `base.BuildRenderTree(__builder)` is to force to call the BuildRenderTree of my base component that the framework doesn't do.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of `ComponentBase`.

Unfortunately `ComponentBase` wasn't built with "Wrapper" functionality in mind, so making it perform that trick is a little convoluted.  The alternative, which I don't recommend when you're new to Blazor, is build your own base component that will support wrapper functionality "out of the box".

The problem with `CustomPage` is that:

```
<h3>CustomPage.razor</h3>
```

is compiled by the Razor compiler into a `protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)` method that overrides yours in the parent component.

To make `ComponentBase` wrap you need to create and manipulate some `RenderFragmnents`.

Here's my demo `MyTemplate`.  It's in your face red so you can see it's wrapping.

It consists of two readonly `RenderFragment` properties.  `Wrapper` is the actual content you want to wrap around the content provided by the child content in `Content`.

```cs
@code {
    protected RenderFragment Wrapper => __builder =>
        {
            <div class="bg-danger m-2 p-1">
                <h3>MyTemplate</h3>
                @this.Content
            </div>
        };

    protected virtual RenderFragment? Content { get; }
}
```

Now our Child - in this case `Index`.  The real content goes into the overidden `Content`.  The content that gets build into `BuildRenderTree` is the parent wrapper RenderFragment defined in `Wrapper`.

```cs
@page "/"
@inherits MyTemplate

@Wrapper

@code {
    protected override RenderFragment Content => __builder =>
        {
            <PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

            <span>Welcome to your new app.</span>

            <SurveyPrompt Title = "How is Blazor working for you?" />
    };
}
```

The result:
[image]

A **NONO**

Don't do this in a builder.

```cs
        var seq = 0;
        builder.OpenElement(seq, "h3");
        builder.AddContent(++seq, "BuildRenderTree of BasePage.cs");
```

Do this:

```cs
        builder.OpenElement(1, "h3");
        builder.AddContent(2, "BuildRenderTree of BasePage.cs");
```

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sequence-numbers-relate-to-code-line-numbers-and-not-execution-order

Comment: If you want to learn a little more about life outside `ComponentBase`, there's an article here that challenges the norm - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5345758/Building-Leaner-Meaner-Greener-Blazor-Components

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I now understand better what the Blazor do when a component inherit from another. The BuildRenderTree of base component is not called, event if a razor component inherits another razor component (both .razor files and non c# code).
The sequence numbers explanation was very clear too. Thank you.